# error on importing pyIpopt

Tags: python, gcc, ubuntu, linker, ipopt

I'm trying to install and configure `pyIpopt`. Ipopt is already installed and the examples run fine.

From the shell, when I do import pyIpopt, I get the error:

```
ImportError: /***PATH***/libipopt.so.1: undefined symbol: MPI_Init
```

The FAQ section of the pyIpopt git project has [this](https://github.com/xuy/pyipopt#miscellaneous-problems) to offer for these kinds of errors:

> Do a Google search to find the library file, and add
>   -lWhateverLibrary in the makefile of pyipopt.

I've googled and found this: http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/www/www3/MPI_Init.html.
I don't know how to get the library or add it to the makefile... Any assistance would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Just had a similar problem on ubuntu.

Using libmumps-seq worked for me:

- installed libmumps-seq-4.9.2 (just with apt-get, along side the ordinary libmumps)
- in setup.py changed in the libraries list argument 'coinmumps' to 'dmumps_seq-4.9.2'

rebuilt and installed.

If I understand it correctly, the default mumps is distributed (using MPI lib which can be a world of pain), and all i needed is the sequential one, which mumps-seq provides.